# Looking for someone experienced in sound for Live Television

Tags: television, recording, mixing, live

I might be called upon to help out on a few live TV show recording/mixing gigs.

Do you have any experience in this area or know the specifics on things like types of microphones, recorders, signal flow, levels information, etc.?

And if so, would you mind if I contacted you and asked a few questions regarding this?

Let me know!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

hey dude, you could probably email me and I may be able to help, I've worked on live TV, some insane shows to some 1 person presenter jobs.

Just fire away with questions!

Comment: anything I can't answer I'll ask my head of department and he may be able to help

Answer (score 1):

I too do daily live television and am available to help you out also.